# Why are my toolbar bookmarks not showing up (It's on "Always show")

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

So I don't know if this is a bug in a new version of Firefox or what, but for some reason my bookmark toolbar is showing up blank. It's appearing in it's place but it's blank. I've checked the "Manage bookmark" settings to make sure I have bookmarks in there and I do, but it's just not showing anything. My bookmarks toolbar is set to "Always show". The screenshot below should show what I mean (the blank area below the address bar).

[image: screenshot of firefox with the problem]

Update: Without doing anything obvious to fix this, the bookmarks came back. Note: It wasn't the result of not having the bookmarks items not added to the bookmarks toolbar in the Firefox customization as one person suggested.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is the subject of the support post
[empty bookmarks toolbar](https://support.mozilla.org/mk/questions/1360272#answer-1464569).

The answer by a moderator was :

> Make sure toolbars like the "Bookmarks Toolbar" are visible.
> You can
> open the Customize window.
>
> - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-firefox-controls-buttons-and-toolbars
> - check that the "Bookmarks Toolbar Items" control is on the Bookmarks Toolbar
> - if "Bookmarks Toolbar Items" is not on the Bookmarks Toolbar then drag it back from the Customize palette to the Customize window to the
>   Bookmarks Toolbar
> - if missing items are in the Customize palette then drag them back from the Customize window to the toolbar
> - if you do not see an item on a toolbar and in the Customize palette then click the Restore Defaults button in the Customize palette window
>   to restore the default toolbar set.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem.  I checked the customization and it showed that my bookmarks were in the right place. Furthermore, if I remove the bookmarks from there and look at it then Firefox places and info message in the place of the bookmark toolbar that says "For quick access, place your bookmarks here on the bookmarks toolbar.", which I wasn't seeing.

Comment: For whatever reason, my bookmarks came back without me doing anything other than waiting.  Not sure what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered exactly the same issue and for me on Windows 11 solution was to *Refresh Firefox* whatever it actually means. I meant to reinstall it but when I started uninstaller I saw this option and decided to go for it. It literally refreshes the install, effects are the same as with reinstallation and now bookmarks from my Bookmarks Toolbar are visible.
[Refresh Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RAKv.png)